# ArrayList.Contains Always Returns False (Checking for an Object)

Tags: vba

I'm trying to utilize an ArrayList in VBA (though it's the same ArrayList as available in C# and VB.net). When checking if an object is in the array list, the output is always false.

Example checking if "anotherPart" already exists in "partsList". Here it should already exist, because an identical "testPart" has already been added:

```
Dim partsList As Object
Set partsList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim testPart As New part
testPart.Number = "10"

partsList.Add testPart

Dim anotherPart As New part
anotherPart.Number = "10"

Debug.Print ("partsList contains: " & partsList.Contains(anotherPart))
```

Debug output:

```
partsList contains: False
```

**Why won't partsList.Contains(anotherPart) return true???**

testPart and anotherPart are different parts, but they are identical, being defined with number="10".
partsList.Contains(testPart) returns true, but I don't understand why partsList.Contains(anotherPart) returns false if anotherPart is the same as testPart?

**Edit to clarify purpose:**
The reason I'm asking this, is I want to check if anotherPart already exists in the list, and only add it if an identical entry is not present. I'd expected to be able to do this, but can't because contains always returns false, and I end up adding tons of duplicate parts:

```
If Not partList.Contains(anotherPart) Then
  partsList.Add anotherPart
End If
```

This seemed to show this as being possible, though they are overwriting the same udtPerson each time. Is there not a way to check this if using a "new" part and not overwriting an existing part? If I'm comparing one list against another for example each object will have been a "new" one.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0160__Collections/UseArrayListContainstocheckifaobjectalreadyexists.htm

Comment: You didn't ADD `anotherPart` to `partsList`

Comment: They're different objects that happen to have the same value in one of their properties. You could use a dictionary, store the `.number` as the key and then the object as an item and do `.exists` to check for the key.

Comment: Your `part` class needs to override the `Equals(Object)` method in order to provide custom equality comparison e.g. `this.Number == other.Number`. Of course, you cannot do that in VBA. You will need to loop and check the `Number` property of each element in the collection to determine if exists or not.

Comment: @SpectralInstance , I would like to check if anotherPart already exists in the ArrayList before adding it, and this is actually why I'm wondering why partsList.Contains(anotherPart) doesn't return true. I've edited my question with an "Edit to clarify purpose" section. Is there not a way to see if an "equal" object already exists? (Sorry to have re-added this, thought I had a typo in your name as it removed the space.)

Comment: The native `Contains` method uses a linear search, so maybe you could write your own function, iterating from 0 to the value of the `Count` property of `partsList`, testing for equality the `number` property of your part with the `number` property of the part returned by `partsList[i]`, where `i` is your iteration variable,i .e. still a linear search, just one you have to write...

Comment: Could you share the complete code from `Sub...` to `... End Sub`? For a while, the ArrayList wasn't running correctly on my computer (Windows 10 64bit Office 2019 64bit) so I abandoned it for good. For it to run, you need to install `.Net framework 3.5`. Additionally, its intellisense wasn't working. A few days ago, I noticed that Windows updated this particular .Net framework version, so if you have a code ready, I would love to give it a try and see if the update fixed any of the issues. Study [the ArrayList on the Excel Macro Mastery website](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/).

Comment: I don't think you get intellisense when using the collection from NET